# Can we always express every closed and bounded set $S\subseteq[0,1]$ as a countable union of intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

A set $S\subseteq [0,1]$ has the property that if $x_1,x_2,\dots$ all belong to $S$ and converge to $x$, then $x$ also belongs to $S$. Can $S$ always be written as a countable union of disjoint intervals?

What is clear is that no interval in $S$ can be open (otherwise taking $x_i$'s to be points converging to the end of the interval gives an immediate contradiction).

Comment: Answer is yes, we can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not clearly stated what is clear; taking $S=[0,1]$ is permitted and $(0,1)$ is an open interval contained in $S$. What you intend is to talk of some sort of maximal subintervals, or maybe you can restrict to disjoint unions.

In any case, the answer is no, if $S$ is e.g. a Cantor set then the only intervals contained in $S$ are closed degenerate intervals (i.e. points). So if $S$ is the countable union of intervals, then it is the countable union of points, so it is countable. But Cantor sets are uncountable.